# Considerations on loading speed with AngularJS one page app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The argument of one-page app with AngularJS is not clear at all to me. Specifically

- why should one prefer one-page apps over standard implementation?
- is there any free service that will turn multiple-pages app into Android app?
- opting to go for one-page app (as they show in their beginner tutorial) what's the best way to implement it so that the website/app (inclusive of User Panel ecc) doesn't become really slow in phones? Loading controllers only when they're called will help significantly? Is there a relevant page in their documentation on how should an app be implemented in multiple pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It really depends on what you want to build, if it's a website, then probably SPA (Single Page App) is not for you, but if it's a web application then SPA is aimed to give the user a more application like feeling (especially when its intended to be used on phones or tablets and wrapped with something like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/))
2. Not sure what you mean, if you want to take an app written with JS/HTML/CSS and make it native on Android/IOS etc. then up-mentioned [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) will do the trick. 
   If you mean that you want to make a multiple page app to a single page app, then NO, there is no service like that, you'll have to manually do it.
3. This is a very complex question and has a lot to do with the way you code and what you build, but you can look [here](http://trochette.github.io/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices/#/intro) or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) for some pointers

Comment: Thank you for this complete and resourceful answer